# How Do I do Real Time Sound/Signal Processing On The iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio, signal-processing, near-real-time

I may be doing an iPhone-based application doing near-real-time sound-processing (filtering, etc). I was wondering the best way to get started. Would I want to create an audio cue for recording and processing sound, as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQRecord/chapter_3_section_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343-CH4-SW1)?

### Edit:

I should be clear. I am not asking how to do signal processing, in general. I know some of that and my team's expert will handle the rest. I asking what the "low level" interfaces to sound data on the iphone are.

### Edit2:

My iphone development has been pushed back a week or two so I don't have access to the deve kit right now. Once I have access to the kit, I'll mark one answer or another correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sound processing is a big subject. AudioQueue will get you the raw data. Apple provides two samples that will get you started using AudioQueue: SpeakHere and AurioTouch.

Comment: Are you sure SpeakHere uses an audio cue, I thought it used a higher level interface - I don't access to Xcode at the moment to see though.

Comment: Yes I am sure Speak Here uses AudioQueue.

Answer (score 2):

I used SpeakHere as a starting point for some audio processing I wanted to do. It's relatively easy to understand, and has all the pieces to do input and output.